# Loop through JSON with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a standard AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json;",
  ...,
  success: function(data){

    // Wanna loop the resultList here...

  }
});
```

...which returns a JSON object which looks like this:

```
{
   "notification": "Search complete",
   "resultList": [
      {
         "id": 1,
         "comment": "lorem"
      },
      {
         "id": 2,
         "comment": "ipsim"
      },
      {
         "id": 3,
         "comment": "dolor"
      }
   ]
}
```

How do I loop though this with jQuery so that the following is printed in the log:
ID #1 - lorem
ID #2 - ipsum
ID #3 - dolor

*Sorry for posting another one of these but I can't figure out how to print this without including the notification. Hopefully this will help others as well..*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you asked for jQuery answer, here's one just for fun:

```
$.each(foo.resultList, function(i, item) {
    console.log('ID #' + item.id + ' - ' + item.comment);
});
```

Comment: Changing this to the accepted answer since I do prefer jQuery in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty simple, you have an *array* of objects:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.resultList.length; i++) {
    console.log(data.resultList[i].id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was stuck thinking I should use .each but this works perfectly.

Comment: For reference (to get exactly what I asked for), it should be something like: `console.log('ID #' + data.resultList[i].id + ' - ' + data.resultList[i].comment);`